# Job interview in London requires me to wire money to the travel agent. Is this a scam?

Tags: visas, uk, payment-cards, travel-agents, scams

I was told that I can have a visitor visa to UK, is this legitimate?

I have received an invitation letter and a job offer, and I was contacted by the appointed travel agent to prepare all related documents for the visit such as flight tickets, accommodation, transportation, and visa application. However, they then asked for deposit money to be transferred to them in London, UK.

The corporate travel agent was appointed by the company that invited me for the job interview in London. They sent a letter of invitation, job offer and travel agent details asking to deal with it and said they will refund all my expenses upon arrival. The travel agent asked me to transfer the deposit for all requirements, then he provided me with an "Emergency Travel Document Form" to be filled in order to start the process.

As well as he asked for "Bank Travel Allowance" to be provided at the borders to secure my stay there and sent me a copy of a MasterCard with my name on it. Then he said he would arrange that visa to be obtained on arrival at the airport with all relevant documents which will be sent to me by "DHL" including the MasterCard, hotel reservation, and hard copy of my entry visa as I said before.

Comment: Please clarify your nationality, and how exactly you intend to be able to work in the UK should you get the job. Also, who asked for deposit money to be transferred? Who appointed the travel agency, and who is paying for the trip? This smells pretty fishy, please provide more details.

Comment: Hold on a moment:  WHO asked for deposit money to be transferred to London?  Who told you to do that?

Comment: Yeah, deposit, bank transfer sets off **"SCAMMER"** alarm bells to me.

Comment: That all sounds deeply weird. An "Emergency Travel Document" is a temporary passport, not a visa/entry clearance. If you have a job offer already, why do you need an interview?

Comment: Which airport is the visa meant to be provided to you at? If the answer is the UK airport, then you should know that airlines will not normally let you board the plane at your starting point if you do not have documentation proving you can enter the country you are going to.

Comment: With regards to your email, I had ealier informed you that our agency will be sending your hard copies of your travelling documents, flight tickets and hotel reservation confirmation receipts. Your Multi Currency Master Card will also be included in the parcel that will couriered hence you wont require any documentation to redeem debit card, and should you require this parcel containing your travelling documents to be mailed to a different address from that which you provided us in your traveler's arrangement form, kindly do so in your next reply.

Comment: That was the last email from them

Comment: Just to clarify -in the UK, a "Job Offer" is an offical action from a company, where they state that you are the candidate that they want, that they are offering you X, Y and Z as compensation, and if you accept, you will be employed, with some provisos for paperwork. Job offers happen **after** interviews, and are not conditional on things like an interview.

Comment: **This is completely fake.** Do not send these people any money or financial information. You will never see them again, and you will find yourself stranded at the airport.

Comment: You should contact the police, even if you don't think the information you shared is important or confidential - you might be unaware of various fraud methods! And of course, the information you provide might help combating these fraudulent practices.

Comment: @GayotFow It seems that Mastercard do in fact have a product called a [Multi-Currency Cash Passport](http://www.mastercard.co.uk/cash-passport.html), "a prepaid card that allows you to load multiple currencies on to one card". (But of course this "job offer" is still very clearly a scam.)

Comment: @Pont, thanks for the heads' up! Also try to put in an answer if you can help the OP further!

Comment: Coming from [The Workplace](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/), a company flying you in for an interview should pay for everything. Even those that are honest about repaying you are a bad idea, because the process can be long and painstaking. As everyone else here has said, run away!

Comment: Did you actually apply for a job with the company that is offering you the job?

Comment: UK Gov Fraud Website: https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/frauds-tricks-and-scams/fraud-tricks-and-scams

Comment: Why they need to transfer funds and then return them? The only explanation is: Fraud.

Comment: While this question in particular asks about a work visa, the same situation could apply for a tourist visa, I'm voting to keep it open

Comment: obviously a scam ...

Comment: @JoeBlow The question is about visas and travel, so it's perfectly on topic here.

Comment: An old trick I learned on 419eater... find a random system file on your computer. Make a copy of it and name it `MTCN.pdf` and send it back. When they gripe, insist that it works on your own computer.

Comment: @JoeBlow Really ? And "_**not even vaguely**_" ?

Comment: @JoeBlow F.ex. visitor visa to UK, travel agents providing emergency travel documents, "Bank Travel Allowance" provided at the borders, obtaining visa on arrival at the airport. I'm not saying anything about whether the question should be closed (this is always hard for me to tell plus I didn't think about that) and you might even be right about that, but due to the above examples I'm sure that the question does not qualify at all as having "utterly no connection" or being "not even vaguely" related to this site.

Comment: My friend told me amazing story recently - it's about how fresh graduates of the russian university went to London just like that and were scammed(no one welcomed them in the airport of course) and they had to work illegally on some junk sorting facility with illegal immigrants from other countries -whole thing controlled by local mafia! I don't know which part of the story is true, but I think it's much more adventurous than just visiting London as a tourist.

Answer (score 174):

Based upon what you wrote, you are getting ripped off. It means you are the victim of a con.

- A UK emergency travel document is issued to British citizens only. They will never issue an emergency travel document to a foreigner.  That's the job of the foreigner's country.
- Issuing a UK work permit (or UK visit visa) at the UK border (or airport) flat out does not happen.  If you need a visa, you need to get one before you depart.  While non-visa nationals do not require a visit visa, you're asking the question and framing yourself as a visa national.
- Visa fees are collected by the UK government as part of the application process.  There's a screen near the end of the application for the applicant to enter payment details.
- Nobody gets in to the UK on a work permit (or visitor visa) without enrolling their biometrics.  Absolutely nobody. To do that the applicant has to print out the form and take it to a [VFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VFS_Global) or similar enrollment centre.  There is no way to avoid a personal appearance and what your agent proposes to do by sending you everything does not account for your personal appearance.
- Nobody gives an interview invitation and job offer at the same time; a company can lose their migrant license for doing that.
- There is no 'hard copy' of an entry clearance. It is a gummed
  vignette affixed to a full blank page of the passport.
- The funds transfer arrangement is, quite frankly, bizarre.  Nobody asks the applicant to pay for the whole ball of wax up front and wire it to a travel agent. Bizarre.

**The Sting**

It's likely that you were enthralled by the prospect of employment in the UK when you were offered a ridiculously attractive package which included a great job, all expenses paid, and a work visa.  They need you to pay all of the expenses in advance and will refund this to you upon arrival.

After you send them the money, they will contact you explaining that an additional advance payment needs to be made to cover an administrative expense associated with your MasterCard. Once you send the additional payment they will contact you advising that another additional payment needs to be made because someone in UK immigration needs to receive a small 'discomfort' fee. Once you have paid that, they will explain that the CEO of your new company doubts your intentions and you will need to put up a payment to demonstrate your sincerity. After that, they will think up something else that you need to pay.

This cycle of additional payments will repeat itself until you are bled dry. After that they will disappear.

> websites that offer jobs in the UK that do not exist. If you apply for
>   one, they tell you that you have the job and ask you to pay visa and
>   work permit fees. That is not how our visa system works, and there are
>   no shortcuts to a job in the UK. A genuine employer would direct you
>   to this website, where you can make an official application. If the
>   job offer sounds too good to be true, it could be a scam. We will
>   never guarantee a job in the UK

Source: [Fraud, tricks and scams](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/frauds-tricks-and-scams/fraud-tricks-and-scams)

**Recommendations**

1. You need to check if the beneficiary of your proposed wire transfer
   is actually in the UK.  Check the [IBAN](http://www.ibancalculator.com/), I rather doubt you'll
   find the account and beneficiary in the UK.
2. Check if your potential employer is [licensed to sponsor
   migrants](https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/492788/2016-01-18_Tier_2_5_Register_of_Sponsors.pdf).  If so, use the company's contact info on their web
   site to assure your beneficiary is not impersonating the company.  I
   would expect that the company is not on the list OR you would be
   unable to call them directly (using their contact us) and verify
   your status.
3. If you sent them your passport, you are in jeopardy of identity
   theft and more fraud. Take all the paperwork to the police and
   explain what happened.

---

Misc Notes

- About getting entry clearance at the border...

  > An applicant for an entry clearance must be outside the United Kingdom
  >   and Islands at the time of the application.

  [Paragraph 28, Immigration Rules](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-part-1-leave-to-enter-or-stay-in-the-uk)

---

- What a scam email looks like...
     [Scam email enquiry](https://www.facebook.com/ukinthephilippines/posts/503939069616567)

Comment: I'm not sure if the work permit stuff is entirley relevant - it sounds like the OP was expecting to travel on a visitor visa for the interview, with a working visa later? Although yes, still reads an awful lot like a scam.

Comment: You don't get to convert visitor visa to a work visa, I don't think. Not while you're in the country. Either way though, yes, scam, absolutely.

Comment: @DewiMorgan, there are no provisions for someone on a visitor visa to switch into a work permit, or anything else. It's simply the spiel sold to the OP by the scammers.

Comment: Good :) Was responding to CMaster's query: "you have to apply outside" is the way it worked for me moving UK to US, and I vaguely remembered reading the UK was similar in that regard.

Comment: It makes no sense to convert a visitor visa to a work visa while in the country.  The requirements are different.  What happens if you are rejected?  You're already in the country for crying out loud!

Comment: I'm not even sure you can legally go job hunting/go for a job interview in the UK while having only a tourist visa. You quite possibly need a business visa (not a work permit, but you're there on business travel, just like anyone coming over for business meetings).'

Comment: @jwenting - no difference. There is just the "UK visitor visa" for both business/tourism. See https://www.gov.uk/browse/visas-immigration/tourist-short-stay-visas

Comment: You can't even have a job interview on a visitor visa.

Comment: @Terry: That's wrong. Among the allowed activities on a general visitor visa is to "attend meetings, conferences, seminars, **interviews**". https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-appendix-v-visitor-rules, Appendix 3, paragraph 5(a). You can't _start work_ after the interview on a visitor visa, though.

Comment: @HenningMakholm it seems you are correct. I understood the meaning of interview to be different from job interview.

Comment: `Issuing a work permit (or visit visa) at the border flat out does not happen`... in the UK. I know that seems obvious, but just in case someone finds this answer in relation to another country: some countries do issue visas at customs

Comment: There are some countries with "visa on arrival", or that allow "visa on arrival" for travelers of selected nationalities, so your second bullet point isn't totally true.

Comment: @sandy A _tourist_ visa on arrival is common enough. A _work_ visa on arrival is almost unheard of.

Comment: @sandy, "An applicant for an entry clearance must be outside the United Kingdom and Islands at the time of the application. "  Paragraph 28, Immigration Rules.  https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-part-1-leave-to-enter-or-stay-in-the-uk

Comment: Visitors to the UK who get stamped in at the airport get 'leave to enter', it's not a visitor visa.  See  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leave_to_enter

Answer (score 29):

One thing that stood out immediately to me (and it was mentioned by Gayot) is that emergency travel documents are given to citizens for travel *to their country of citizenship* and not to a foreign country. There are some exceptions (like refugees and asylum seekers - but these do not apply to you).

I have been flown in to another country for interviews before. You (as the applicant) to do not pay for the travel ticket or the hotel accommodation. It is all arranged in advance by the company inviting you.

Further, the company will send you an official letter of invitation - sometimes, they send this directly to the concerned embassy.

You still have to go through all the processes of obtaining a visa - collection of fingerprint data, filing of the application, arranging for an appointment, appearing in person (if required) and so on.

Despite all this - there is a chance you can be declined the visa.  There are no guarantees and anyone offering you these is trying to take advantage of you.

---

I have been employed my entire professional life as an expat, here is the almost universal process that I have seen (across four countries and two continents) - and this (or a close approximation) is what you should expect to go through if you are being courted by a genuine employer.

If the process does not go like this - or is short circuited, especially if **payment is asked upfront** - immediately stop as its is someone trying to take advantage of your situation.

1. The first interview is over the phone or Skype. There may be multiple interviews.
2. If an in-person interview is required, and travel is required - the company pays all expenses (as detailed above). There is no guarantee of employment at this point either.
3. After the interview process, if successful, you are given an official employment offer. This is a document that has (at minimum) your job role/title, start date, compensation (basic pay + any benefits). It is normally signed by the company, and there is a place for you to sign - signaling you have accepted the offer.  Normally, this document is not the employment **contract**; which is drafted once the offer is accepted. The reason I mention this is because the contract is what you need as supporting document at the embassy, not the offer letter.
4. Once the offer letter is accepted - the company starts drafting your employment contract. This has further details about your job, it may include additional information about your benefits. This is a **legally binding document**. At the same time, they will ask for your personal details such as **copy of your passport** (they will never ask for the real thing) to prepare for your visa process.
5. After some time (the exact time depends on the country, and the type of job you are being offered) - you will receive documents from your employer that they have *applied for a visa on your behalf*; along with a copy of the application.
6. Next, you take this document, a copy of your employment contract, your passport, and anything else that is required by the embassy (sometimes, these include medical tests!) and apply for a work visa (or whatever visa type is offered to you by the company). If your application is successful, you are granted the visa to travel.
7. Depending on your contract - you may not be required to pay for your trip to the country (some contracts include relocation assistance, which helps with things like paying to move your furniture, arranging for temporary accommodation for you while you find permanent housing, etc. etc.) - normally though, you have to pay for this ticket yourself and arrive in the country.
8. Once you enter the country and start your first day at the job, you will be required by HR to file further paperwork; and depending on the country you may be required to go through additional immigration formalities.

Comment: As a note, there may be exceptions for foreign workers, but it's becoming common practice in the UK for the emplyer to refuse to share the contract with employees until the first day of employment. Also, UK Embassys do not handle the visa process at all these days.

Comment: It depends on the type of hire they are doing - I am not personally familiar with UK hiring practices, but a colleague of mine (a consultant) had a copy of his contract in hand before he left here. You are right about the embassy not handling applications - I will make this more explicit in my answer.

Comment: @CMaster: I don't claim any specific knowledge of UK hiring practices, but how on earth is it possible to negotiate an employment contract while not showing it to one of the parties that are negotiating it? How can there even be a "first day of employment" before the negotiations are completed and the prospective employee has agreed to the result?

Comment: @HenningMakholm if it goes like in the Netherlands you're usually getting a draft of the contract by email with a statement that your employment will start on such and such a date if you mail back your agreement. Then on the day you get there you find the paper contract ready to sign. Or you even get the contract as a PDF, presigned by the company, as an email, which you sign and bring with you on your first day or send back by regular mail. Getting a signed contract mailed to you  on paper is rare these days.

Comment: @jwenting: Sure, but CMaster's comment sounds like the contract is _kept secret_ from the new hire until the first day of employment. I know if I were changing jobs, in Denmark, I wouldn't give notice to my old employer until I had a mutually agreed-to contract text in hand -- I wouldn't demand ink signatures on paper, though.

Comment: @HenningMakholm The broad terms are understood and discussed. It's legally possible to work like this (with a verbal/implied contract) in the UK. Mostly, it seems to be to gain leverage over the employee "well you're here now, with no alternative employment, so you're less able to dispute the terms". I suspect it changes as you get "higher up" the career ladder, but this happens routinley (source, my partner's last 2 roles (although not her current), my current role)

Comment: It's perhaps worth pointing out that there is something of a cultural change developing here. For people coming out of degrees etc in their life now "contract" doesn't mean negotiated agreement to them. It means "take it or leave it imposed terms". That's how their University contract was, how their phone contract, their internet, dozens of other examples (and may incorrectly beleive their housing contracts too) that they have signed before beginning "formal" employment.

Comment: @HenningMakholm same here. Unless the offer letter were a legal document and bound the company to the terms and conditions (including pay, work hours, etc.) to be detailed in the contract I'd never leave an existing job based on it, and if it's not enough to get a work permit it's apparently not legally binding.

Comment: @CMaster and so are for most of us job contracts as well. In markets where there's a glut of candidates for every job the company can pretty well dictate the terms of employment and get their pick of candidates still.

Comment: @CMaster: All I can say is that if someone I had applied to tried to pull that on me, I would conclude they're not really interested in employing me after all, tell them so in no uncertain terms, and wish them luck in finding other marks for their scam.

Comment: @HenningMakholm and you should be glad you are in a position to be able to do that. Lots of people (especially early career) aren't so awash in job offers. It's also worth mentioning that I'm only aware of the outright refusal happening once or twice - normally it's just mentioned casually "oh, we'll take care of that when you start".

Comment: @CMaster: One doesn't need to be "awash in job offers" in order to walk away from such shenanigans. Simply being currently employed will suffice. (And if you're currently _unemployed_, then it won't cost you much to play along and show up on the ostensible first-day-of-work to find out if the offered terms are acceptable or not, anyways. (That is, if it's not half a planet away, of course. But if your skills are in enough demand that companies will fly you around the planet just to interview you -- as is ostensibly the case in this question -- then certainly you're able to walk away too)).

Comment: It's also probably worth noting that whether an employment contract even exists will vary by regional custom. Formal employment contracts are not customary in the U.S. for most types of positions, for example.

Answer (score 14):

On your inital question: You can apply for a visitor visa with validities as long as 10 years (although individual visits are limited to a shorter duration). Note that while a visitor visa would be valid for attending an interview, you would have to convince the visa office that you intended to return home after the interview, then apply freshly for a working visa and work permit. [You can read more about types of visa, and the rules for them, on the offical UK government website, gov.uk](https://www.gov.uk/browse/visas-immigration)

However, various elements of your story suggests that there is no real chance of a job for you here, and that you would be denied a visa to the UK due to your confused evidence anyway. You mention that the documents you received contain a "job offer". In the UK, a "job offer" letter would take roughly this format:

> Dear *Applicant*,
>
> *Company Name* would like to offically offer you the role of *job title*, with a salary of *£XX,XXX* per year (plus additional benefits, please see the company handbook). The intended start date of your emplyment would be *dd/mm/yyyy*. This offer is conditional on receipt of valid references and confirmation of your legal right to work in the UK.
>
> If you have any queries, please contact *contact name, email address*, or please *perform paperwork actions* to confirm your acceptance of the offer.

The offer is received after all interviews etc have been performed and you have been selected as the/one of the candidates for the role. You would not receive an offer before an interview and if you were to include an offer letter in a visitor visa application, it would work against you, as it would be evidence that you intended to work and not leave the country, in opposition to the rules of a visitor visa.

On top of this, the situation with the travel agent is very strange. If a company is expecting you to travel across the world for an interview, then return, then travel again to relocate to the country, then one would normally expect them to bear the costs. There are employers who might not do this, but they would normally then not expect you to attend an in person interview. In the event that you were expected to fund the trip yourself, or even fund the trip yourself and later be reimbursed by the employer, then you would be free to make your own arrangements, and **not** simply approached for money by their travel agent.

The travel agent's statements and requirements are themselves highly suspect. The requirement for a bank transfer (internationally!) immediatly raises red flags. Bank transfers (along with Western Union, Moneygram, etc) have no procedures for refunds, meaning once the money leaves your account it is gone, even if you can prove it was sent to a fraudster. Any reputable (even small) UK travel agent would be capable of accepting card transactions.

The claim of having your visa (and other documents) delivered to you at the airport seems to be a way of making you not realise the nature of the scam until the last moment. Any real visa will require involvement from you in the process, inclduing a trip to a visa fascilitation centre. You won't be able to board a plane to the UK without having a valid visa (or visa-exempt passport), so if the airport you were meant to receive this at was in the UK, then that is too late.

One of the other answers suggests that you may also be approached for additional money to "ease" the way through UK beaurocracy and officals. You should know that this is not the way things work in the UK. Officals are sufficently well paid that they do not need a steady stream of small bribes to support themselves, and the penalties for being involved in such behaviour are massive. This is not to say that there is no corruption in the UK, but it is either more subtle and not relevant to this process, or considerably out of the price range of anyone looking for employment.