# UK visit visa for a job interview- financial and employment proof

Tags: visas, uk, indian-citizens, work, proof-of-employment

I am an Indian citizen. I plan to go to UK for an onsite job interview with an overnight stay and return back to India next day. I need an advice regarding  financial documents submission.

- I am an unemployed person, but I have a job offer for which I can submit job offer letter.
- I am aware about personal financial documents submission for which I can submit bank statements which shows that I have enough balance for a one day stay, but a trust in India is sponsoring my travel to UK for air and visa expenses.
- Is it OK to submit their letter of sponsorship with their registration number or will be my application be refused on this ground?

Comment: In general you have to show your own financial situation regardless of how much money you are personally spending on the trip. If anyone else is contributing toward the cost of the trip, you need to submit information to support that, too. There's no rule however, against someone else paying for your trip, though there needs to be a credible explanation of why they would want to.

Comment: Welcome to Travel SE. Adding to the great comment above, have a look to [Should I submit bank statements when applying for a UK Visa? What do they say about me?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/66104/32134). The other documents you mention would support your application but make sure they state your name and the purpose of your trip without any discrepancies from your story. Also make sure there are no unfulfillable promises, e.g. do not have a letter where a sponsor guarantees that you will come back, as nobody is able to guarantee such a thing and it raises suspicion.

Comment: Um, if you have a job offer, then why are you traveling to job interviews? By definition, those happen _before_ an offer is extended. And why is it "a trust in India", rather than the prospective employer in the UK that will pay for your travel?

Comment: @HenningMakholm thank you for your answer. I have a job offer after I got an invitation letter for assessment day in UK, i.e. I was interviewed at same time but got call for assessment day first and then the mentioned job letter with an extension to join. The prospective employer in my case is reimbursing my expenses limited to travel in UK. Since I would be travelling from India, arrangement of visa and air expenses would be borne by trust which I mentioned.

Comment: You won't get a visit visa if you already have the offer of a job - after all, you have no need is an interview is the job has already been offered to you. You may want to read all of this http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/61529/26433