# Asked to send emergency travel money by MoneyGram, is this a scam?

Tags: money, scams, fraud, work-permit

The employer offered to pay all the visa and travel and is now in the process of work permits. The issue is the advocate referred to has requested that I deposit money into MoneyGram into my name being sent by a relative in my name as a emergency or travel allowance which will cater for my needs in the first month before I get my salary. Is this legit?

Comment: No, it's a scam, 100% guaranteed. Run away!

Comment: Think about it: if you have enough money to cater for your living expenses in the first month of employment, why do they want you to put it into a MoneyGram account instead of just leaving it in your own bank account or taking it with you in cash? Do you have any reliable evidence other than through a 3rd party ‘advocate’ (whatever that is) that this ‘offer’ comes from a genuine employer? Your instinct is telling you this doesn’t look legit, listen to that voice.

Comment: Rule #1: If you have to ask: it's a scam!

Comment: @Hilmar Rule #2.  See Rule #1

Answer (score 28):

**You are being scammed.**  The "job" you are being "hired" for does not exist.  This is a classic form of advance fee fraud, since a legitimate employer will *never* ask you to pay money upfront for anything.  Asking to use MoneyGram is also a huge red flag, since anybody with the code can collect the money and there is no way to reverse the transaction.

Here's a similar case with good advice: [Job interview in London requires me to wire money to the travel agent. Is this a scam?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/61529/job-interview-in-london-requires-me-to-wire-money-to-the-travel-agent-is-this-a)

Comment: The scammers may have nothing to do with the actual job application, except they hacked someone's personal data. Anecdote: I got in touch by email with an old high-school friend. I knew he was a keen chess player. Soon after,, I got an email purportedly from him, saying he was at a chess tournament in Eastern Europe, had lost all his travel documents and credit cards etc, and requesting me to send money so he could get back home. This obviously made no sense -why didn't he ask his family, instead of me? - and of course I ignored it.